# How to use Windows font in a LaTeX document?

Tags: windows, fonts, latex, miktex

How do I use a Windows font in a LaTeX document? Is it even possible? If yes, how?

I am on Windows XP and using the [**MikTeX**](http://miktex.org/) system for LaTeX. My LaTeX editor is [**LEd**](http://www.latexeditor.org/). I fell in love with the free [**Fontin**](http://www.josbuivenga.demon.nl/fontin.html) font. I have installed it into my Windows fonts and can use it with Word and other Windows apps. Now I would like to use it in my LaTeX documents.

**Note:** I know how to use the pre-installed fonts inside MikTeX with LaTeX documents. This query is specifically about using fonts in Windows (outside of MikTeX) with LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [XeLaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) which can use any installed OpenType font just fine, even with advanced typographic features, if supported by the font.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "drag-and-drop" way of making that work. I used to do this on a regular basis some 10 years ago when I was still at uni and could choose my document writing environment as I pleased. Those were good days...

Some links to get you started:

- http://www.rubli.info/linux/latex_opentype.txt
- http://igor.gold.ac.uk/~mas01rwb/latexConvertFonts.html